# Crossfading HTML5 audio logic

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I'm trying to crossfade HTML5 audio (not webaudio) and use an equal-power crossfading curve:

```
var gain1 = Math.cos(x * 0.5 * Math.PI);
var gain2 = Math.cos((1.0 - x) * 0.5 * Math.PI);
```

But I'm having some logic problems with this.

Let's say I have two instances of sound, Sound1 & Sound2, both have the same source.

It's easy to crossfade them if Sound1 is playing at full volume (`1.00`) and I want to end up playing Sound2 at full volume after the crossfade. I would just need to loop x's value from 0 to `100` and set gain1 as Sound1's volume and set gain2 as Sound2's volume.

But what if I'm currently playing Sound1 at `0.75` volume and I want to end up playing Sound2 at the same volume after the crossfade.

**How do I calculate the correct range for x?** Where to begin and where to stop looping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must multiply the calculated gain:

```
var original_gain1 = 1.0;
var original_gain2 = 0.75;

var final_gain1 = original_gain1 * Math.cos(x * 0.5 * Math.PI);
var final_gain2 = original_gain2 * Math.cos((1.0 - x) * 0.5 * Math.PI);
```

What you need for a simple crossfade is an asynchronous loop. With the following code you can start loops to increase x from 0 to 1, and back. These functions will call updateGains in every cycle.

```
var x = 0;

var crossfade_speed = 0.05;

function crossfadeTo1()
{
    // if we havent reached 1.0
    if ( x<1.0 )
    {
        // increase x
        x += crossfade_speed; 

        // continue the asynchronous loop after 200ms (it will update volumes 5 times a second)
        setTimeout( crossfadeTo1, 200 );            
    }
    else
    {
        // set x the maximum ( we can go over 1.0 in the loop )
        x = 1.0;

        // we dont call the function again, so the loop stops
    }

    // call your function with x to update gains
    updateGains( x );     
}       

function crossfadeTo0()
{
    // if we havent reached 0.0
    if ( x>0.0 )
    {
        // decrease x
        x -= crossfade_speed; 

        // continue the asynchronous loop after 200ms (it will update volumes 5 times a second)
        setTimeout( crossfadeTo0, 200 );            
    }
    else
    {
        // set x the minimum ( we can go under 0.0 in the loop )
        x = 0.0;

        // we dont call the function again, so the loop stops
    }

    // call your function with x to update gains
    updateGains( x );     
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more how would you use this code with 2 audio elements in your page? Each audio needs to call different function?